# Compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with the upper semicontinuity topology has a maximum

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $\mathbb{R}_{usc}$ be the real line equipped with the "upper semicontinuity topology" that is the topology where a nonempty set is open iff it is of the form
$(-\infty, a)$ with $a \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$.

Prop: Every nonempty compact set of $\mathbb{R}_{usc}$ has a maximum.

Proof:

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}_{usc}$ be a nonempty compact set.

$A$ has an upper bound: $\mathcal{A}=\{(-\infty, n) | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{R}_{usc}$ then it is also an open cover of $A$. Since $A$ is compact there is a finite subset $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{F}=\{(-\infty,n_1), \dots , (-\infty,n_m) \}$ s.t. $A \subset \ (-\infty,n_1) \cup \dots \cup(-\infty, n_m) = (-\infty, \max\{{n_1, \dots , n_m\}})$ and then $\max\{{n_1, \dots , n_m\}} \ge x$ for every $x \in A$. And then $\sup{A} \ne +\infty$.

$\sup{A} \in A$ : if not $\{(-\infty, \sup{A}-1/n) | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is an open cover of $A$ and there is not an open subcover and then $A$ is not compact.

Is it correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well... correct.

Comment: Looks good! ${}{}$

Comment: @Famke,  I mean "it has a maximum".

Comment: @Bremen000 , What do you mean by the term ***admits a maximum***? So what do you mean by the term ***it has a maximum***?

Comment: @Famke $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ has a maximum if there is $x \in A$ s. t. $x \ge y$ for every $y \in A$. How can I say it in english?